# Silverlight 4.0 - image cropping with mouse events

Tags: silverlight, image, silverlight-4.0, crop

I have a task to build image cropping functionality in Silverlight 4.0 application. What I need to do is to have user on the left button mouse click select area to remain after cropping is applied and then call some other event (button click maybe) to apply that cropping itself.

I did develop similar functionality for rotation. I am pretty sure it is possible to do for cropping as well but that task is probably rare at this point for I can't find tutorials on the topic in the net.

If you guys can get me a snippet to begin with or point to some good tutorial about Silverlight 4.0 image cropping, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as cropping images are concerned you can use the [WriteableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library on codeplex.

Now you just need to draw a rectangle on a canvas containing the image to describe the crop region.

Comment: Thank you Anthony, that library is definitely a start.